# Subset of data.table excluding some columns

Tags: r, data.table

I need just to exclude set of columns from my `data.table`. I can do it by using `-c()` with numbers of these columns:

```
dti <- data.table(iris)
dti1 <- dti[, -c(3,5), with=F]
```

but I would like to use column names instead of numbers, something like

```
colsExcl <- c('Petal.Length', 'Species');
dti1 <- dti[, -c(colsExcl), with=F] # error: invalid argument to unary operator
```

Comment: It works for me without any error.

Comment: @Metrics, really? What version of "data.table" are you using?

Comment: @AnandaMahto: I am using 1.9.5.

Comment: @Metrics, maybe they've integrated some different behavior in the development version then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `setdiff` or `:= NULL`, but the behavior is different.

With `setdiff`, you'll have to assign the output to another object:

```
colsExcl <- c('Petal.Length', 'Species')
dti1 <- dti[, setdiff(names(dti), colsExcl), with = FALSE]
```

By contrast, using `:= NULL` removes the columns from your original `data.table`:

```
dti[, (colsExcl) := NULL][]
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width
#   1:          5.1         3.5         0.2
#   2:          4.9         3.0         0.2
#   3:          4.7         3.2         0.2
#   4:          4.6         3.1         0.2
#   5:          5.0         3.6         0.2
#  ---                                     
# 146:          6.7         3.0         2.3
# 147:          6.3         2.5         1.9
# 148:          6.5         3.0         2.0
# 149:          6.2         3.4         2.3
# 150:          5.9         3.0         1.8
```

Comment: ah, I just wanted to avoid using `names(dti)`... But I missed the solution with `:= NULL`, and in fact I can escape modifying original table by using `copy()`, like this: `dti1 <- copy(dti)[, (colsExcl) := NULL]`. Thank you for both solutions!